# Papervision performance

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, papervision3d

Is it too much to render 900 triangles in papervision ? 
I know the CPU model also affects, I'm using a core2duo 1.7GhZ. But rendering 900 triangles, as 5 cylinders seems too much, and drops the performance when rotating them for examples each frame... The FPS at normal is ~30FPS, but it drops when rotating or spinning the cylinders to 14~FPS. I'm really surprised about that performance, as Quake or Doom they were purely software rendering engines, and they had much more polygons than my application and they had a better performance of course.

Comment: Quake and Doom are native applications: machine code running straight on the OS as opposed to as3 code which runs in the AVM in the Flash Player plugin, in the browser, on top of the os. a lot of layers in between. Use Away3D (version 3.6 or Lite for the non molehill / Flash Player 10 version) or 4 and onwards for Molehill hardware acceleration (although you can specify not to use the GPU if you want). Papervision hasn't been updated for a few good years now as opposed to Away3D. 3/4 years ago I did get ~2000 triangles with PV3D though. Are you using filters/layers/etc. ?

Comment: I'm not using any layers or any filtering, just drew 5 cylinders as reels, textured. That's all I had. They are rendered fine, but when rotating all of them, the frame rate drops to the half.
Thanks for explaining the issue, I forgot that Flash is based on a  virtual machine...

Comment: the framerate probably drops because the engine is busy recalculating the views when rotating. although it won't look as nice, you can try to reduce the number of segments on the cylinders, keep it a bit lower poly: speed vs. quality trade of. You can possibly do some quality change on the fly: if the scene is animating reduce quality, when animations end, render in higher quality again (stage.quality for now). Are you using any transparent textures ?

Comment: I also thought about reducing the number of segments, but the quality matters unfortunately. I'm using normal mapping textures, but I'm drawing over the cylinders few symbols, which are normal bitmap images, so that when they rotate, the symbols rotate too. Is it possible to change the quality on the fly ?

Comment: You really should look into porting the app to Away3D, which originated as a fork of Papervision, but leverages Stage3D for rendering, which means it uses the GPU for all the heavy lifting. Performance wise, even 100,000 triangles is not a problem for Away3D.

Comment: @George Profenza I got the real bottleneck. They are loading a large texture of a strip which contains an 128*128 pictures that form a slot reel, there are 36 symbols... That's why I think the performance is really bad while also rotating the reel. I want to know how to optimize that ?

Comment: so you are using 36 textures 128x128 ? bitmaps/static or movieclips/animations ?

Comment: they are just bitmaps, coming from .png files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's roughly the limit that you're going to get with Papervision, as it's not taking advantage of hardware acceleration.  If you're looking to take advantage of some of that hardware you're throwing at the problem, look into Away3D (http://away3d.com/).

Comment: How did you know that 9000 triangles are roughly the limit ? Are not there 3D Games that are written using papervision and has higher polygons ?

Comment: Lots of trial & error & optimization in my previous life as a Flash developer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting from the Papervision book "Papervision3D Essentials":

- Always try to model using as few polygons as possible.
- Papervision3D users often wonder what the maximum number of triangles is that the Flash player can handle. There is no generic answer to this question, as performance depends on more factors than just the number of triangles. On average, the total triangle count should be no more than 3000, which equals 1500 polygons.
- Keep your textures small (in size and resolution)